# Performance impact of accessing child objects in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I convert my DB objects to interface objects when extracting data from the database and found that when I convert objects that have child objects, I see a significant performance impact.

My model

```
public class NumberRange
{
    public NumberRange()
    {
            ReservedNumbers = new HashSet<ReservedNumber>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ReservedNumber> ReservedNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class ReservedNumber
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public Guid NumberRangeId { get; set; }

    public virtual NumberRange NumberRange { get; set; }

}
```

Establishing the foreign Key as follows

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<NumberRange>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ReservedNumbers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.NumberRange)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.NumberRangeId);
```

And the code to convert to interface models (extension methods)

```
public static Models.NumberRange ToApiObject(this Model.NumberRange obj, bool includeAssociatedLocations = false, bool includeReservedNumbers = true)
{
    var apiObj = new Models.NumberRange { Id = obj.Id };
    if (includeReservedNumbers)
        apiObj.ReservedNumbers = obj.ReservedNumbers.OrderBy(n => n.Number).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ToApiObject()).ToList();
    else
        apiObj.ReservedNumbers = new List<AUDMService.Models.ReservedNumber>();
    return apiObj;
}

public static Models.ReservedNumber ToApiObject(this Model.ReservedNumber obj)
{
    return new Models.ReservedNumber { Id = obj.Id, Number = obj.Number, NumberRangeId = obj.NumberRangeId };
}
```

If I now extract a list of NumberRanges with ReservedNumbers

```
var myList = context.NumberRanges.OrderBy(n => n.Name).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ToApiObject(includeDependentElements, true));
```

I see a long delay with large data sets (I have ranges that have ~1000 reserved numbers). I figured I could include ReservedNumbers

```
var myList = context.NumberRanges.OrderBy(n => n.Name).Include(n => n.ReservedNumbers).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ToApiObject(includeDependentElements, true));
```

yet, that has no discernible impact.

I then came up with this, which solves the performance issue

```
var myList = context.NumberRanges.OrderBy(n => n.Name).Include(n => n.ReservedNumbers).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ToApiObject(includeDependentElements, false));
addReservedNumbers(myList, context);

private void addReservedNumbers(IEnumerable<Models.NumberRange> ranges, DatabaseContext context)
{
    var rangeIds = ranges.Select(x => x.Id);
    var reservedNumbers = context.AccessibleReservedNumbers.Where(x => rangeIds.Contains(x.NumberRangeId)).AsEnumerable();
    var convertedNumbers = reservedNumbers.Select(x => x.ToApiObject());
    foreach (var range in ranges)
        range.ReservedNumbers.AddRange(convertedNumbers.Where(x => x.NumberRangeId == range.Id));
}
```

So I'm wondering.. isn't there a way to get my first approach to run as fast as the second one?

Comment: It is difficult to follow all the code, but I think your problem is that you end up calling ToList() at multiple levels and times, so each one sends a single request to the DB.  I bet you are sending hundreds or thousands of queries to the DB instead of 1 or 2, so that'll greatly impact performance.

Comment: When you select children, the query ends up exploding.  If possible, select the children directly and include the parent.  Then if you need to return the parent, simply select distinct all parents from the child records in memory and you'll be good to go!

Comment: @DanielLorenz: Unfortunately, most parents have no children, but I need all parents and all their children. On an SQL level, I'd like to have an OUTER join of NumberRanges (parent) and ReservedNumbers (child). Isn't there a way to do that using EF?

Comment: You can by using the other style of linq the var query = from a in ctx....  However, if you need recursion for this, you may want to right custom SQL and use CTE instead.